# How to do a proper upsert using sqlalchemy on postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to do an upsert using the "new" functionality added by postgresql 9.5, using sqlalchemy core. While it is implemented, I'm pretty confused by the syntax, which I can't adapt to my needs.
Here is a sample code of what I would like to be able to do :

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    a_id = Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = Column("a",Integer)

engine = create_engine('postgres://name:password@localhost/test')
User().metadata.create_all(engine)
meta = MetaData(engine)
meta.reflect()
table = Table('test', meta, autoload=True)
conn = engine.connect()

from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert as psql_insert
stmt = psql_insert(table).values({
    table.c['id']: bindparam('id'),
    table.c['a']: bindparam('a'),
})
stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=[table.c['id']],
    set_={'a': bindparam('a')},
)
list_of_dictionary = [{'id':1, 'a':1, }, {'id':2, 'a':2,}]
conn.execute(stmt, list_of_dictionary)
```

I basically want to insert a bulk of rows, and if one id is already taken, I want to update it with the value I initially wanted to insert.
However sqlalchemy throw me this error :

```
CompileError: bindparam() name 'a' is reserved for automatic usage in the VALUES or SET clause of this insert/update statement.   Please use a name other than column name when using bindparam() with insert() or update() (for example, 'b_a').
```

While it is a known issue (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/VwiUlF1cz_o), I didn't found any proper answer that does not require to modify either the keys of list_of_dictionary or the name of your columns.

I want to know if there is a way of constructing stmt in a way to have a consistent behavior that does not depends on whether the keys of the variable list_of_dictionary are the name of the columns of the inserted table (my code works without error in those cases).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

this does the trick for me:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

def upsert(engine, schema, table_name, records=[]):

    metadata = MetaData(schema=schema)
    metadata.bind = engine

    table = Table(table_name, metadata, schema=schema, autoload=True)

    # get list of fields making up primary key
    primary_keys = [key.name for key in inspect(table).primary_key]

    # assemble base statement
    stmt = postgresql.insert(table).values(records)

    # define dict of non-primary keys for updating
    update_dict = {
        c.name: c
        for c in stmt.excluded
        if not c.primary_key
    }

    # cover case when all columns in table comprise a primary key
    # in which case, upsert is identical to 'on conflict do nothing.
    if update_dict == {}:
        warnings.warn('no updateable columns found for table')
        # we still wanna insert without errors
        insert_ignore(table_name, records)
        return None


    # assemble new statement with 'on conflict do update' clause
    update_stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        index_elements=primary_keys,
        set_=update_dict,
    )

    # execute
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(update_stmt)
        return result
```

Comment: I didn't knew the stmt.excluded, which is what I needed. I have on an other hand no idea of why you are trying to exclude primary keys, set={c.name : c for c in stmt.excluded} seems to just work as intended (i don't mind "updating" a primary key, as it's by definition the same value)

Comment: oh that is a good point. would make the code at least a bit more elegant.

Comment: Does this work with `execute(query)`?  `query` is never defined anywhere.  Should it be `execute(update_stmt)`?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right - i've updated the code block to reflect that.

Comment: What is `insert_ignore` i don't see that function in your imports, also what is records? Is a list or a list or dict?

Comment: sorry - assume `insert_ignore()` is a function defined elsewhere in the file that ignores instead of updates conflicting rows. `records` is a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an ORM solution, the following worked for me:

```py
def upsert(
    sa_sessionmaker: Union[sessionmaker, scoped_session],
    model: DeclarativeMeta,
    get_values: Dict[str, Any],
    update_values: Dict[str, Any],
) -> Any:
    """Upserts (updates if exists, else inserts) a SQLAlchemy model object.

    Note that get_values must uniquely identify a single model object (row) for this
    function to work.

    Args:
        sa_sessionmaker: SQLAlchemy sessionmaker to connect to the database.
        model: Model declarative metadata.
        get_values: Arguments used to try to retrieve an existing object.
        update_values: Desired attributes for the object fetched via get_values, 
            or the new object if nothing was fetched.

    Returns:
        Model object subject to upsert.
    """
    with sa_sessionmaker() as session:
        instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**get_values).one_or_none()
        if instance:
            for attr, new_val in update_values.items():
                setattr(instance, attr, new_val)
        else:
            create_kwargs = get_values | update_values
            session.add(model(**create_kwargs))
        session.commit()
        instance = session.query(model).filter_by(**get_values).one_or_none()
    return instance
```

A few remarks:

- If the primary key of the object is known, using [Session.merge()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge) is likely a better alternative than the function above. In that sense, the function above assumes that the primary key is not known (and hence not part of `get_values`)
- `sa_sessionmaker` is a factory for `Session` objects (see the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#using-a-sessionmaker))
- `model` takes a SQLAlchemy declarative metadata (i.e., a "table" see the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#orm-declarative-table-configuration))
- Python >= 3.9 required for the implementation above. If your environment requires a previous version of Python, replace `create_kwargs = get_values | update_values` with `create_kwargs = {**get_values, **update_values}`

Comment: This has a race condition because it handles the get_or_create in Python instead of in the database. You're going to get `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError` raised eventually with this code.