# SQLAlchemy insert from select raises bindparam error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy on PostgreSQL, I try to improve performance at insertion (about 100k egdes to insert), executing "nested inserts" in a single query for one edge and its nodes.

Using `Insert.from_select`, I get following error and I don't really understand why.

```py
CompileError: bindparam() name 'name' is reserved for automatic usage in the VALUES or SET clause of this insert/update statement.   Please use a name other than column name when using bindparam() with insert() or update() (for example, 'b_name').
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import *

metadata = MetaData()

node = Table('node', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
)

edge = Table('edge', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('source_id', Integer(), ForeignKey(node.c.id)),
    Column('target_id', Integer(), ForeignKey(node.c.id)),
)

engine = create_engine('postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432')
metadata.create_all(engine)

e1_source = insert(node).values(name='e1_source').returning(node.c.id).cte('source')
e1_target = insert(node).values(name='e1_target').returning(node.c.id).cte('target')
e1 = insert(edge).from_select(
  ['source_id', 'target_id', 'name'],  # bindparam error
  # ['source_id', 'target_id', 'b_name'],  # key error
  # [edge.c.source_id, edge.c.target_id, edge.c.name],  # bindparam error
  select([
    e1_source.c.id,
    e1_target.c.id,
    literal('e1'),
  ])
)
engine.execute(e1)
```

EDIT: Below, the SQL query I was expected to produces. I remain open to any suggestions to achieve my purpose though.

```sql
CREATE TABLE node (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE edge (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   source_id INTEGER REFERENCES node (id),
   target_id INTEGER REFERENCES node (id),
   name VARCHAR
);

WITH source AS (
  INSERT INTO node (name)
  VALUES ('e1_source')
  RETURNING id
), target as (
  INSERT INTO node (name)
  VALUES ('e1_target')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO edge (source_id, target_id, name)
SELECT source.id, target.id, 'e1'
FROM source, target;
```

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724658/how-to-do-a-proper-upsert-using-sqlalchemy-on-postgresql/43527774   when he is trying insert use insert_ignore

Comment: Thank your for helping, but I didn't see the relation between the issues except he is also encountered a `binparam` error. I have finally found the solution of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured out where `bindparam` was implicitly used by SQLAlchemy to solve my issue: in the node queries and not the edge query as I was first thinking.

But I am still not sure if this is the proper way to perform nested insert queries with SQLAlchemy and if it will improve execution time.

```py
e1_source = insert(node).values(name=bindparam('source_name')).returning(node.c.id).cte('source')
e1_target = insert(node).values(name=bindparam('target_name')).returning(node.c.id).cte('target')
e1 = insert(edge).from_select(
  ['source_id', 'target_id', 'name'],
  select([
    e1_source.c.id,
    e1_target.c.id,
    literal('e1'),
  ])
)
engine.execute(e1, {
    'source_name': 'e1_source',
    'target_name': 'e1_target',
})
```